# Cannot unprotect Excel worksheet in VBA (Run-time error 32809)

Tags: vba, excel

The code has worked on this machine previously. I worked from home yesterday on a machine which hasn't had the December 2014 Office updates removed.

I get the same error when running a little for loop which you can see commented out. Any suggestions? The sheet exists. Unhidden. Not password-protected.

Thank you!

Comment: Can the December 2014 Office updates be removed?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be using `ActiveWorkbook`? If you want the loop to apply to the workbook that the macro is in, use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Comment: Copy *MAIN SCOPE* from the module code sheet and paste it into the name tab of the intended worksheet.

Comment: Unfortunately if you share a workbook between computers that don't all have the updates applied (or all lack them), you can have problems like this. If you can use Forms controls instead, I'd recommend it; faililng that, I suggest you recreate the worksheet and make sure all computers using it are at the same level of updates.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening early in the code, the worksheet might be corrupted. Copy and Paste that sheet to a new sheet and try again.

I know it's not a very in depth solution but I would try this before going crazy with different strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I was able to solve this problem by following a bit of guidance from elsewhere, however.

I put a Worksheet.Select line in at the start of each Sub - just a simple line of code with no impact. Voila. Working since.

I'll stick to making mods on the one machine I use most frequently... for now.